# Easiest Pattern to Recognize with Machine Vision

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, object-recognition

I need to detect the exact position of some kitchen tools using machine vision. I've the possibility to label the tools with a pattern, to make the detection (more specifically the image segmentation) easier.

What is the easiest pattern to detect using machine vision?

The pattern should be:

- Easy detect in presence of partial occlusions.
- Easy to detect with varying and degraded light conditions.
- Easy to detect with widely used computer vision algorithms, in particular lightweight algorithms that can run on edge devices.
- Hard to mistake for another object (in a kitchen).
- Possibly carrying some additional information.

A QR code fits this description pretty nicely. My guess is that the easiest pattern will contain a sharp alternation of two colors, likely black and white.

Comment: In a video or a single image?

Comment: The tool is static, so single image is fine.

Comment: [Is this question and answers any use?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8821/what-are-some-easy-to-detect-reference-mark-shapes-and-corresponding-detection-m/8822#8822)

Comment: Yes. I just discovered these fiducial markers, for instance AprilTags: https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag

Comment: See also https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10687/what-the-name-of-this-kind-of-computer-vision

Comment: With your permission for clarity I added the links you wrote in the answer. For 1 spot answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (which I've upvoted), but I'm not sure fiducial markers are the final answer, hence I'm leaving it open for now.

Comment: @Rexcirus, Did you end up with something better than my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In case you can shoot a video of the static scene than a blinking light would be the easiest as you could easily detect it by subtracting the `n - 1` frame from the `n` frame until you see something with high values.

If you take a still shot you can use 2 main ideas:

1. If the colors of the scene are from a given plate, find a color very different in Hue and make sure it is intense (Even active lighting which will saturated).
2. Use a pattern which is easily detectable like stripes of B/W or pure green and magenta. You may encode data in the stripes.

#### Resources

Some resources pasted here in comments:

- [Fiducials / Fiducial Markers](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8822).
- [AprilTag 3](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag) - A visual fiducial system popular in robotics research.
- [What the Name of This Kind of Computer Vision](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10687)? (Related question).